# Collision detection of two arcs in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, constructor

I am trying to detect if two balls are intersecting on a HTML5 canvas.
I need a function called intersect as a part of a constructor object called Ball.
This function will take one Ball object as an argument and return true if the two balls on the canvas are touching/ intersecting. and false otherwise.

I cant figure out how to pass in a new instance of a ball to the intersect function and then compare it to another ball on the canvas.
The function I'm working on the is the final function intersect at the end of the Ball Object.
Please see below for the code i have so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<hmtl>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    canvas{
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <canvas id="canvasOne" ></canvas>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Gets a handle to the element with id canvasOne.
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");

        // Set the canvas up for drawing in 2D.
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
        canvas.width  = 500;
        canvas.height = 500;

    function Ball(xpos,ypos,r) {
        this.xpos = xpos;
        this.ypos = ypos;
        this.r = r;
        this.move =  function(addx,addy){
            this.xpos = this.xpos + addx;
            this.ypos = this.ypos + addy;
        };
        this.resize =  function(setr){
            this.r = setr;
        };


        this.draw = function(){ 

            for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(ball.xpos, ball.ypos);
                ctx.arc(ball.xpos, ball.ypos, ball.r, i*(2 * Math.PI / 7), (i+1)*(2 * Math.PI / 7));                    
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.strokeStyle = '#444';
                ctx.stroke();
            }

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(ball.xpos, ball.ypos);
            ctx.arc(ball.xpos,ball.ypos,ball.r-10,0,2*Math.PI);
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#444';
            ctx.stroke();

        };
        this.rotate = function(){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // Move registration point to the center of the canvas
            ctx.translate(ball.xpos, ball.ypos);

            // Rotate 1 degree
            ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180);

            // Move registration point back to the top left corner of canvas
            ctx.translate(-ball.xpos, -ball.ypos);

            ball.draw();

            ctx.restore();

        };
        this.contains = function(x, y){
            this.x = this.x;
            this.y = this.y;
            if(Math.sqrt((x-ball.xpos)*(x-ball.xpos) + (y-ball.ypos)*(y-ball.ypos)) <= ball.r)
            {
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        };

        this.intersect = function(){
            this.ball1 = this.ball1;

            var distance = (ball.xpos * ball.xpos) + (ball.ypos *ball.ypos);
            if(distance <= (ball.r + ball.r)*(ball.r + ball.r)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        };

    }

    var  ball = new Ball(100,100,100);
    ball.draw();




    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if you aren't going to use the `this` keyword in your class, then why make it a class?

You can setup your `intersect` to take a `Ball` as a parameter. From here you can calculate the collision between `this` and the parameter `Ball`.

You distance function was off, as it only looked on the `this` object, and i fixed the `this` problem in your code:

```js
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
// Set the canvas up for drawing in 2D.
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

function Ball(xpos, ypos, r) {
  this.xpos = xpos;
  this.ypos = ypos;
  this.r = r;
  this.move = function(addx, addy) {
    this.xpos = this.xpos + addx;
    this.ypos = this.ypos + addy;
  };
  this.resize = function(setr) {
    this.r = setr;
  };
  this.draw = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.xpos, this.ypos);
      ctx.arc(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.r, i * (2 * Math.PI / 7), (i + 1) * (2 * Math.PI / 7));
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.xpos, this.ypos);
    ctx.arc(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.r - 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
  };
  this.rotate = function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // Move registration point to the center of the canvas
    ctx.translate(this.xpos, this.ypos);
    // Rotate 1 degree
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180);
    // Move registration point back to the top left corner of canvas
    ctx.translate(-this.xpos, -this.ypos);
    this.draw();
    ctx.restore();
  };
  this.contains = function(x, y) {
    this.x = this.x;
    this.y = this.y;
    if (Math.sqrt((x - this.xpos) * (x - this.xpos) + (y - this.ypos) * (y - this.ypos)) <= this.r) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
  //put "ball" as a paremeter
  //ball will be the foreign Ball to test intersection against
  this.intersect = function(ball) {
    var productX = this.xpos - ball.xpos;
    var productY = this.ypos - ball.ypos;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(productX * productX + productY * productY);
    if (distance <= (this.r + ball.r)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
}
var ball1 = new Ball(100, 100, 100);
var ball2 = new Ball(240, 140, 40);

function update(evt) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if (evt !== void 0) {
    ball2.xpos = evt.offsetX;
    ball2.ypos = evt.offsetY;
  }
  //Pass the ball as an argument to the method
  ctx.strokeStyle = ball1.intersect(ball2) ? "red" : '#444';
  ball1.draw();
  ball2.draw();
}
update();
canvas.onmousemove = update;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I cant figure out how to pass in a new instance of a ball to the
>   intersect function

Well to pass anything really it should have an argument.

```
this.intersect = function(otherball){
 // then compare the two ball objects
```

Then...

```
var ball1 = new Ball(100,100,100);
var ball2 = new Ball(100,100,100);
ball1.draw();
ball2.draw();

console.log(ball1.intersect(ball2));
```